# Input quote, output in caps, lower case and reverse

Tags: python, reverse, uppercase, lowercase

I'm trying to make a program in Python 3 (IDLE) which lets the user input a quote and outputs it in upper case, lower case and in reverse. I've tried this:

```
quote = input("Enter your quote here: ")
print(quote.upper())
print(quote.lower())
print(quote.reverse())
```

...but all I get back when I test it is this error text:

```
Enter your quote here: You are always unique.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shobha m nair\Documents\Quote Conversion.py", line 2, in <module>
    quote = input("Enter your quote here: ")
  File "<string>", line 1
    You are always unique.
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You're using Python 2 where `input` runs `eval` on the result.

Comment: You're looking for `raw_input`.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using Python 2.x that's why you got the unexpected behaviour. The following code ran fine with Python 3.5:

```
quote = input("Enter your quote here: ")
print(quote.upper())
print(quote.lower())
print(quote[::-1])
```

There is no "reverse" method for strings.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

`quote = input("Enter your quote here: ")
print(quote.upper())
print(quote.lower())
print(quote[::-1])`

The last one is the extended splice operator. AFAIK there's no reverse method in Python 3.

Comment: Note that this will not work in Python 2, and cause exactly the issue described in the question.

Comment: Yes, but didn't he specifically say he's using Python 3?